# EA documentation for a view use case

Tags: enterprise-architect

For this web project, a table listing is implemented in many different places (~60 tables, as in jqgrid tables showing information from db). The table functions are mostly the same (sort, filter, pagination, some custom actions) but there are specific requirements for these (columns to be sorted/filtered, table actions, ...).

I am trying to come up with a *right* way to model every table with it's specific details. For this I created some default Tagged Values, which I fill in by hand (e.g. table headers = id, special name, direction). I created a default use case "View table" which I copy as a new instance in the use case diagrams for each of the packages that define the tables.

My questions are:

1. The way I did it doesn't seem to let me to link the default activity diagram to the use case instance (RClick on use case -> New child diagram -> Select composite diagram => doesn't open the window "select a diagram"). How can I do this ?
2. If the way I did it seems wrong / not a good practice, how could I do it better ?

Answer (score 0):

1. To create (and link) activities for a use case Add/Activity/with AD from the project explorer for the UC. That will create it inside the UC where it belongs. item
2. You'd be better served with a simple profile that creates the TVs automatically. See here: http://community.sparxsystems.com/tutorials/552-24intro-to-creating-a-mdg-file